# How to have horizontal separator below title bar without using UINavigationController in XIB?

Tags: ios, swift

In StoryBoard, if we were using `UINavigationController`, the embedded `UIViewController`, will automatically come with a title bar, with horizontal separator.

### Using UINavigationController in StoryBoard

[image]

### Horizontal separator (Circled in red)

[image]

---

If we are using XIB, it is not possible to place `UINavigationController` in XIB. Hence, in order to have title bar. We need to place it manually.

### Added title bar (navigation bar) manually in XIB

[image]

However, with such approach, I am not getting the horizontal separator as shown below.

### No horizontal separator

[image]

May I know if I were using XIB, how can I have a horizontal separator below title bar, without using `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Adding a navigation bar manually is not a good idea. Judging by your screenshot, you are presenting the collection view modally. You can instantiate a navigation controller and present that instead.

Comment: @Desdenova - many reasons to add a `UINavigationBar` to a controller that is *not* in a navigation controller stack. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @DonMag Sure but it's not about being right or wrong, it will present its own problems. The answer you post may be sufficient for the OP since he is presenting the view controller. But instead if he wants to push the controller, than you'd have to attach the bar to top through bar positioning delegate to fill the safe area space. And there is standard/scroll to edge appearances that needs to be handled. What I meant was, it all comes free with a single line of code.

Comment: No. I do not need to push additional view controller. That's why having navigation controller is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the views in the view hierarchy...

Here's how it looks in the order you've setup:

[image]

output:

[image]

If we move the Navigation Bar to the bottom of the list of subviews - thus bringing it to the **Top** of the view hierarchy:

[image]

It now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually , NavigationBar has already a horizontal seperator but you couldn't see because of your `collectionview` 'under the `navigationbar`' top constraints might be zero. That cause collectionview covers the horizontal seperator.

When you use `NavigationController`all the componens in viewcontroller settle down under the `navigationBar` but if you use like you posted , They all in the same line . Thats why giving zero top constraints make causes the cover horizontal seperator.

You can change the top constraints of collectioview  and you going to see the seperator.